# Docker COPY issue while building the docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a project which is Maven based multi module project

It has various modules with in, like common-utils, web, theme, etc, etc

And also in the root location it has the `Dockerfile` which is not default one but I have named it `Dockerfile.cli` due to some requirements

Dockerfile.cli contents here:-

```
FROM tomcat

ENV NEUW_LOG_HOME /neuw/web/logs

RUN echo "running the image, making it a container :-)"

RUN mkdir -p "/neuw/web/theme-v4"

COPY web/target/web.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war

COPY theme-v4 /neuw/web/theme-v4

CMD ["catalina.sh", "jpda", "run"]
```

Now why I am here -> am getting the below error while building the image:-

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder838877607/web/target/web.war: no such file or directory
```

The command I use to run the image build is like below and running it on the `root` of the project which contains both `theme` and `web` folder:-

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.cli -t neuw/web:snapshot-30 .
```

Any hints and help for the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which directory are you in when you run this command? Could you do `ls /web/target/` from that directory? I ask because I think your Dockerfile is expecting to find a web.war in ./web/target relative to the directory you are running in.

Edit (to save anyone digging through the comments on this): The target directory did contain the file but it was invisible to docker due to a .dockerignore file with **/target.

Comment: I am on windows machine, so the folder /web/target exists - that am sure

I am in the `root` folder of the project which contains both `theme` and the `web` folders

Comment: What do you see when you run `ls /web/target/`?

Comment: the web.war file in the target folder

Comment: Could you check the permissions on the files e.g. with `ls -ltr`? I just ran: 
`touch web.war` from /web/target/
`touch Dockerfile.cli`
`vi Dockerfile.cli` and pasted your Dockerfile content
then `docker build -f Dockerfile.cli -t neuw/web:snapshot-30 .` and I got `COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder382177037/theme-v4: no such file or directory` Which is the line after the war file is copied. So the line that failed for you worked for me. This suggests to me that my docker can see the war file I created and yours can't.

Comment: Yes from the root folder that I created. I created /web/target/ under that dir and went into that directory from the command-line. Sorry I didn't realise you were on windows - I assumed you were on unix because of /var/lib error.

Comment: that helped I was having the .dockerignore with **/target, removed that and it worked, thanks a lot